# How to move all files back to the local GIT repository?

Tags: git

I made unintended changes in my local source files and would like to move all files back to the local GIT repository at the same branch.  How to do this?

Comment: Please elaborate, by source files you mean files on the remote?

Comment: local source files, thanks. I corrected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can also be achieved with

```
git reset
```

to recall the last *staged* versions of the files,  or

```
git reset --hard
```

to recall the last *committed* versions of the files

You might also give a *commit-id* (*sha*, *branch name*, *tag* or *relative commit index* (eg.: HEAD^^)) to reset the branch to.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the git checkout command: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Comment: with `git checkout` you need to specify the *branch* or *commit* you want the version from and the  *file* you want to throw away the local changes...